# Trouble setting up mirroring on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, mirroring, sql-server-2016

I've setup a test SQL Server 2016 server.  I've installed 2 instances, restored a backup on the primary.  Then restored a backup on the secondary with `NO RECOVERY`, then restored the transactional log on the secondary, also with `NO RECOVERY`.

I then followed the prompts in the Mirroring Wizard off the Database Properties page and ended up getting an error:  `Database 'Ares' cannot be open.  It is in the middle of a restore`.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Are both service accounts running under the same user? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5302/why-are-my-sql-server-2008r2-databases-not-mirroring  It might be an issue with SSMS, have you tried setting it up using T-SQL?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverfaq/2009/03/31/setting-up-database-mirroring-in-sql-server-2008-using-t-sql-when-the-database-is-encrypted-using-transparent-data-encryption/

Comment: @stacylaray Yes, under the same user.

Comment: Do you have unique ports for both the instance ports and the mirroring ports?  You will not be able to use 5022 for both instances because they are on the same server.

Answer (score 4):

For information, I had the same issue.

This is a bug in SSMS 2016, the easiest solution if to connect using an older version of SSMS (Like 2014) to run the mirroring wizard and it works like a charm.

You can also set it up using command line but it's more complicated.